# access denied for user 'root'@'localhost - first time installed

Tags: php, mysql

i just installed the mysql and now i want to access it. i have check the mysql has been running. when execute mysql.exe in cmd it's always show an error :

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using
>   password: NO)

i try to googling, and they commonly say it has problem with the password (?)
but i haven't do anything other than using instalation tutorial :(
i also try to run

> mysqld --skip-grant-table

what is that command for  ?

[help]

Comment: there is no [help] tag. Remove that from your question please.

Comment: have you assigned your root password?

Comment: hi btw, i just try to reinstalling it and its work. now i have no idea where is that problem come

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is possible that you set password to user** `root`.
In this case you need to reset password for `root`.

Create a text file containing the password-assignment statement on a single line. Replace the password with **your** .

MySQL 5.7.6 and later: 
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';

MySQL 5.7.5 and earlier: 
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('MyNewPass');

Save the file ge: to `C:\mysql-init.txt` .

`Start the MySQL server with the special` --init-file option (notice that the backslash in the option value is doubled): 
C:> cd "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin"
C:> mysqld --init-file=C:\mysql-init.txt

If you installed MySQL to a different location, **adjust the cd command accordingly**.

The server executes the contents of the file named by the --init-file option at startup, changing the 'root'@'localhost' account password.

To have server output to appear in the console window rather than in a log file, add the --console option to the mysqld command.

If you installed MySQL using the **MySQL Installation Wizard** , you may need to `specify` a --defaults-file option.

For example: 
C:> mysqld --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini" --init-file=C:\mysql-init.txt

The appropriate --defaults-file setting can be found using the Services Manager: From the Start menu, select Control Panel, then Administrative Tools, then Services. Find the MySQL service in the list, right-click it, and choose the Properties option. The Path to executable field contains the --defaults-file setting.

After the server has started successfully, **delete** C:\mysql-init.txt.

> I have some problem few years ago and do like here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: thankyouuu sirr the explanation really good

Comment: I already fix the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

the command you need is this:

```
mysql -u user -p<password here>
```

Comment: Ok, but the console says something new?

Comment: the issue is now cant acces local host 10061 but i already fix it by change the value innodb_buffer_pool_size :)

Comment: You solve problem or no? Or have other problem?

Comment: sudo mysql_secure_installation

Answer (score 0):

Run config script from mysql dir

```
shell> ./configure
```

Comment: i just reinstall it and it works, now i just restart my computer and the problem come back *frustated